# New column based on mixed number/text column

Tags: powerbi, dax, directquery

I have a column `column1` in powerbi where the majority of rows are Numeric and the minority is Text.

How can I calculate `column1` multiplied by another column `columnX` in a new column, while ignoring rows where `column1` is Text. The new column should contain Blank for these rows.

I am using the `DirectQuery` method so I can't change the data type of `column1`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
Product =
IF (
    ISERROR ( VALUE ( 'Table'[Column1] ) ),
    BLANK (),
    VALUE ( 'Table'[Column1] ) * 'Table'[ColumnX]
)
```